# Can I restrict deletion of web content only with approval using Liferay 6.2?

Tags: liferay-6

Currently when deleting web content it doesn't require approval, can I use Kaleos Workflow or another configuration to always request approval when deleting web content?

Curently, We have a Kaleos workflow for content approval.